# Pygame Moving a box results in increment of size of box

Tags: python, pygame

Initially there is a box,I want to move the box by increment or decrease in position of the box.What I get is it looks like object is scaling right or left.I am using pycharm and python 3.5.

```
__author__ = 'GK'
import pygame

green = (0,255,0)
black = (0,0,0)
pygame.init()
GameDisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Momo Killer")
x= False
lead_x = 300
lead_y = 300

while x is False:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      quit()


    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            lead_x -= 20
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            lead_x += 20

pygame.draw.rect(GameDisplay,green,[lead_x,lead_y,20,20])
pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

By using the above code I get this(Shown in pic).

[image: Output when using code]

Answer (score 2):

you should clear the display before you draw onto it again each frame, like:

```
while x is False:

    GameDisplay.fill([0,0,0])
    #...
    #...
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: glad i could help for once :-)